# Nearest neighbour search in a constantly changing set of line segments

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, kdtree

I have a set of line segments. I want to perform the following operations on them:

1. Insert a new line segment.
2. Find all line segments within radius R of a given point.
3. Find all points within radium R1 of a given point.
4. Given a line segment, find if it intersects any of the existing line segments. Exact intersection point is not necessary(though that probably doesnt simplify anything.)

The problem is algorithms like kd/bd tree or BSP trees is that they assume a static set of points, and in my case the points will constantly get augmented with new points, necessitating rebuilding the tree.

What data-structure/algorithms will be most suited for this situation ?

Edit: Accepted the answer that is the simplest and solves my problem. Thanks everyone!

Comment: For item 3: where do the points come from? Are they static, or somehow defined by the line segments?

Comment: Using the term 'nearest neighbour' in your question may be misleading, as this is not the same as 'all points within a given distance of a line', or 'all points within a given radius of another point'. Nearest neighbour typically implies a single result, and does not equate to 'within a given point to point or point to line distance'.  The difference here may invalidate some of the otherwise solid answers given such as Davids.

Comment: @Erik P. The points are ends of the line segments. Line segments may share endpoints.

Comment: @Shane I realized later that "all points within radius" is a easier problem than k nearest neighbor. Apologies. But the answers are nonetheless interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is dividing your space into a grid of boxes - perhaps 10 in the y-axis and 10 in the x-axis for a total of 100.

Store these boxes in an array, so it's very easy/fast to determine neighboring boxes.  Each box will hold a list vector of line segments that live in that box.

When you calculate line segments within R of one segment, you can check only the relevant neighboring boxes.

Of course, you can create multiple maps of differing granularities, maybe 100 by 100 smaller boxes.  Simply consider space vs time and maintenance trade-offs in your design.

- updating segment positions is cheap: just integer-divide by box sizes in the x and y directions.  For example, if box-size is 20 in both directions and your new coordinate is 145,30.  145/20==7 and 30/20==1, so it goes into box(7,1), for a 0-based system.

Comment: The size of the box can be max(R, R1). Now the only expensive part is updating each box when I add a line segment. Bresenham can help with that. Interesting answer.

Comment: updates are cheap - by using integer division in the x and y directions (by the box-size in the x and y directions), you can index directly into the box you want (no need to search)

Comment: @kfme04, Depends very much on how regular the data is in terms of spacing and line length.  Works well for reasonably regular spaced data.  If you have a lot of clumps with big spaces in between, and lines of very different sizes, you could run into problems.

Answer (score 2):

Maintaining a dynamic tree might not be as bad as you think.

As you insert new points/lines etc into the collection it's clear that you'd need to refine the current tree, but I can't see why you'd have to re-build the whole tree from scratch every time a new entity was added, as you're suggesting.

With a dynamic tree approach you'd have a valid tree at all times, so you can then just use the fast range searches supported by your tree type to find the geometric entities you've mentioned.

For your particular problem:

- You could setup a dynamic geometric tree, where the leaf elements
  maintain a list of geometric entities (points and lines) associated
  with that leaf.
- When a line is inserted into the collection it should be pushed onto
  the lists of all leaf elements that it intersects with. You can do
  this efficiently by traversing the subset of the tree from the root
  that intersects with the line.
- To find all points/lines within a specified radial halo you first need 
  to find all leaves in this region. Again, this can be done by traversing 
  the subset of the tree from the root that is enclosed by, or that 
  intersects with the halo. Since there maybe some overlap, you need to 
  check that the entities associated with this set of leaf elements 
  actually lie within the halo.
- Once you've inserted a line into a set of leaf elements, you can find 
  whether it intersects with another line by scanning all of the lines 
  associated with the subset of leaf boxes you've just found. You can then 
  do line-line intersection tests on this subset.

A potential dynamic tree refinement algorithm, based on an upper limit to the number of entities associated with each leaf in the tree, might work along these lines:

```
function insert(x, y)

find the tree leaf element enclosing the new entitiy at (x,y) based on whatever 
fast search algorithm your tree supports

if (number of entities per leaf > max allowable) do

    refine current leaf element (would typically either be a bisection 
    or quadrisection based on a 2D tree type)

    push all entities from the old leaf element list onto the new child element
    lists, based on the enclosing child element

else

    push new entity onto list for leaf element

endif
```

This type of refinement strategy only makes local changes to the tree and is thus generally pretty fast in practice. If you're also deleting entities from the collection you can also support dynamic aggregation by imposing a minimum number of entities per leaf, and collapsing leaf elements to their parents when necessary.

I've used this type of approach a number of times with quadtrees/octrees, and I can't at this stage see why a similar approach wouldn't work with kd-trees etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How would you balance this tree ? The tree can become lopsided (albeit in the worst case) and this will reduce performance dramatically.

Comment: I believe you have pointed me towards R trees (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree). Thanks!

Comment: The level of imbalance in the tree is dependent on your data. It's often stated that real-world data is reasonably well distributed, making worst-case behaviour unlikely practice - I would try first and see whether you have a problem before worrying about re-balance operations. Also note that it's only kd-like trees, which are split according to a median criteria that could be affected by the order in which points are added, and hence re-balancing. Trees that have a fixed geometric refinement (quadtrees/octrees etc) will give you the same result regardless of insertion order.

Comment: If you really need re-balancing you can look at re-building the subset of the tree that is affected by the insertion/deletion. In many cases this is still much faster than rebuilding the whole tree.

Comment: Good points. I am looking at building fictitious road networks so it should be reasonably distributed. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Interesting answer, could be fun to see whether a TIN or tree based approach would be faster for this application.  If it's road data, with proximal points presented in order, I'd go for a constrained TIN as you also get a full surface model you can render as a by-product.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin: It would be interesting to see how the run-times stacked up - maybe you need a weekend coding project ;). Generally, I like the fast randomised search capabilities of tree-based methods, but as you say, if the data is presented in sequence, a triangle traversing method could work well. I also like the multi-grid triangle methods you mention in another comment.

Comment: @Darren, I'm a little bit biased in favour of TINs, having spent the last 20 years or so developing surface modelling software, and very little with trees.  You can search spatially on a TIN very quickly, where search time is based on the number of triangles traversed from the start point, which is regularly an adjacent triangle, e.g. O(1) for many searches that take place around a similar proximity.  Space overhead is higher, ~2 triangles per point, 6 indexes (points+neighbours) per triangle.  Random searches will be slower, typically O(sqrt(n)), and are dependant on the shape of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inserting and deleting into a tree you can calculate a curve that completely fills the plane. Such a curve reduce the 2d complexity to a 1d complexity and you would be able to find the nearest neighbor. You can find some example like z curve and hilbert curve. Here is a better description of my problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem.

Comment: How do you store line segments in a z curve ?

Comment: @SidDatta: I don't think this will work but you can calculate a z curve instantly. It's just another way to see a quadtree. BTW. When you micro optimize which itself is bad practise, i.e. avoid a tree I don't think there is a faster method then my method.

Comment: @David, interesting answer, but reading the question suggests Sid isn't actually looking for nearest neighbours.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin: I mean this problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Answer (score 1):

While items 2 & 3 are relatively easy, using a simple linear search with distance checks as each line is inserted, item 4 is a bit more involved.

I'd tend to use a constrained triangulation to solve this, where all the input lines are treated as constraints, and the triangulation is balanced using a nearest neighbour rather than Delaunay criterion.  This is covered pretty well in [Triangulations and applications by Øyvind Hjelle, Morten Dæhlen](http://books.google.ie/books/about/Triangulations_and_applications.html?id=cRXAe8CVbBYC&redir_esc=y) and [Joseph O'Rourkes Computational Geometry in C](http://books.google.ie/books?id=viRhQgAACAAJ&dq=editions%3aqiN4HYtychIC&hl=en&ei=1wMhT_iLKs67hAeC46H8BA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=book-thumbnail&resnum=2&ved=0CDUQ6wEwAQ)  Both have source available, including getting sets of all intersections.

The approach I've taken to do this dynamically in the past is as follows;

- Create a arbitrary triangulation (TIN) comprising of two triangles
  surrounding the extents (current + future) of your data.
- For each new line
- Insert both points into the TIN.  This can be done very quickly by
  traversing triangles to find the insertion point, and replacing the
  triangle found with three new triangles based on the new point and
  old triangle.
- Cut a section through the TIN based on the two end points, keeping a
  list of points where the section cuts any previously inserted lined. 
  Add the intersection point details to a list stored against both
  lines, and insert them into the TIN.
- Force the inserted line as a constraint
- Balance all pairs of adjacent triangles modified in the above process
  using a nearest neighbour criterion, and repeat until all triangles
  have been balanced.

This works better than a grid based method for poorly distributed data, but is more difficult to implement.  Grouping end-point and lines into overlapping grids will probably be a good optimization for 2 & 3.

Note that I think using the term 'nearest neighbour' in your question is misleading, as this is not the same as 'all points within a given distance of a line', or 'all points within a given radius of another point'.  Nearest neighbour typically implies a single result, and does not equate to 'within a given point to point or point to line distance'.

Comment: +1, This is nice, although finding enclosing triangles by traversal doesn't in general achieve the fast `O(log(N))` type of performance that you get from queries on a tree-like data structure. It's still fast though, much better than `O(N)`.

Comment: @Darren, depends very much on the data organisation.  For randomly organised data, trees will win.  Much data collected by surveying and other observational methods tends to present points close to one another, and if you start your TIN traversal from the last inserted point, the traversal is extremely quick.  i.e. based on the number of triangles crossed, which is very often 0 or 1.  For random data you can achieve great speeds using pyramids (CDPs) to create multi-resolution TINs.